# Tuple assignment to mutable struct parameters

Tags: methods, rust, tuples

I’m getting an error I’m not sure how to handle, related to a tuple assignment I’m trying. The `incr` function below gets a `left-hand of expression not valid` error. What am I misunderstanding?

```
struct Fib {
    i: u64,
    fa: u64,
    fb: u64,
}

impl Fib {
    fn incr(&mut self) {
        self.i += 1;
        (self.fa, self.fb) = (self.fa + self.fb, self.fa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the helpful error explanation says<sup>†</sup>, you try to assign to a *non-place expression*.  A *place expression* represents a memory location, and thus it can be a variable, a dereference, an indexing expression or a field reference, but a tuple is not one of these.

If you would use a *binding*, such as:

```rust
let (x, y) = (1, 2);
```

that would be a whole different story because `let` statements have different rules than assignment: the left hand side of a `let` statement is a pattern, not an expression, and `(x, y)` is a legal pattern.

To solve your problem, you may want to do the following and introduce a temporary variable, and then update the values of the members:

*(The following is also fixing your fibonacci sequence, i.e. correcting the values of the members since they are naturally ordered as 'a' and 'b')*

```rust
impl Fib {
    fn incr(&mut self) {
        self.i += 1;
        let fa = self.fa;
        self.fa = self.fb;
        self.fb += fa;
    }
}
```

> **Note:** Albeit it was not your question, I would strongly advise to implement [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) for your `Fib` type, in which case you wouldn't have to keep track of the index (`i`) because that would be available through the `enumerate` method.
>   E.g.
>
> ```rust
> impl Iterator for Fib {
>     type Item = u64;
>     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
>         let fa = self.fa;
>         self.fa = self.fb;
>         self.fb += fa;
>         Some(fa)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And then you could use it as:
>
> ```rust
> for (i, x) in my_fib.enumerate() { ... }
> ```

---

<sup>†</sup> [`rustc --explain E0070`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0070)

Comment: Super clear, awesome explanation, and the recommendation about the Iterator trait is super useful! Thanks for that :)

Comment: Also, thanks for suffering a Rust newbie, the links you provided gave me a sense of how I might approach similar situations to this in the future.